# How can I create a gradient for a gauge to create a depth effect / perception in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I would like to create a gradient for a gauge in flutter which recreates a gradient close to the example pictures with a depth perception. Can somebody post an example which gets close to the example? Preferable in flutter dartpad. My gradients don't get any near to that example I posted. 
Thanks a lot.

[image: Top right closeup]

[image: Bottom Left closeup]

[image: Overview Image]

Comment: all of them are linear gradients, are you using `CustomPainter` to draw them?

Comment: Yes,I know that. I just don't get that result.